# Convert a CIFAR 1d array from pickle to an image (RGB)

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, pickle

EDIT: **separation of classes**. The original pickle file gives a dictionary with labels, data (array) and filenames. I just filtered the arrays according to class labels and appended all arrays to form a list and then pickled this list together.

```
class_index= 9 #gives the corresponding class label in the dataset
images = [] #empty list 
for i in range(len(labels)):
    if labels[i]==class_index:
        images.append(data[i])
```

with this I get a list of arrays corresponding to just one class say dog.
then I just dump them in a pickle file

```
with open('name.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(images0, f)
```

When I load a pickle file it gives me an output of arrays each of which is shaped (3072,).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

#Load the pickle
images = np.load('name.pkl',allow_pickle=True)
```

I need to get them as RGB images (32,32,3). These are the approaches tried

```
image = images[0]
img = np.reshape(image,(32,32,3))
im = Image.fromarray(img)
```

this gives a very distorted image looks like 9 images of the same item which I think is due to the reshape

[image: image distorted]

Is there a way to avoid this?
I have also tried

```
image = image.reshape(-1,1)
pict = Image.fromarray(image,'L')
plt.imshow(pict)
```

which gives the following image as output 
[image: empty image]

Can someone please help me out? Other approaches are also welcome

Comment: Where did you get the original `pickle`? Did you make it? How? It looks like your array has the color dimensions mixed up with the spacial dimensions.

Comment: It is the CIFAR-10 pickles. But I modified it to contain just one class of data together which is my requirement

Comment: Your modifications is probably what mixed it up, can you edit your question to show what you did?

Comment: Sure I have added that as well. But I don't see how appending two different lists of arrays can have issues with spatial dimensions since I am keeping arrays same. I access each array one by one while getting the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is essentially the reshape command. Since in deep learning the input images are defined as `[batchsize, channels, height, width]` so to see the image in its proper form you should resize it to shape `(3,32,32)`.

Here is a minimal code to get the desired output:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('pickleFile.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    imgList= pickle.load(f)

img = np.reshape(imgList[0],(3,32,32)) # get the first element from list

# inorder to view in imshow we need image of type (height,width, channel) rather than (channel, height,width)
imgView=np.transpose(img, (1,2,0))

plt.imshow(imgView)
```